# Do the docs lie about DBD::Pg's AutoCommit?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

From the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/DBD-Pg-2.17.1/Pg.pm#Transactions):

> According to the DBI specification the default for AutoCommit is a true value. In this mode, any change to the database becomes valid immediately. Any `BEGIN`, `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` statements will be rejected. **DBD::Pg implements AutoCommit by issuing a `BEGIN` statement immediately before executing a statement, and a `COMMIT` afterwards.**

My test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=test");
print "AutoCommit = $dbh->{AutoCommit}\n";
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO foo(x) VALUES (1)');
```

Script output:

> AutoCommit = 1

And my logs (with `log_statement = 'all'`):

> 2012-03-05 20:21:02 CST rootLOG:  statement: INSERT INTO foo(x) VALUES (1)

(forgive me for testing my script as root!)

Where's the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` I was promised by the DBD::Pg docs?

Comment: @AntonioDolcetta: True enough, but the test results are the same for any statement I put in there. Question updated.

Comment: The sentence quoted in bold seems to actually describe (albeit not clearly) what happens when AutoCommit is OFF. When AutoCommit is ON, there's nothing to do since the PostgreSQL server will commit immediately any SQL statement unless a transaction has been previously started with the BEGIN statement. The SQL server itself has no support for autocommit ON/OFF, it's what the DBI docs refers to as "Databases in which a transaction must be explicitly started"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have concluded, through my own testing, that this is a bug in the DBD::Pg documentation.  Accordingly, I have filed [Bug #82356](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=82356) with CPAN, which was resolved Feb 8, 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what AutoCommit=1 does is mark the session as AUTOCOMMIT on the server side, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html.
To make sure we have to look into dbi::Pg source though.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable guess... I wonder why the docs seem to indicate that it emulates that behavior in the client code.

Comment: I'm guessing (so many guesses!) that DBI does wrap BEGIN and COMMIT around statements for databases that do not natively support AUTOCOMMIT

Comment: A fair guess, but the docs for DBD::Pg should know better.  I'm guessing (whoa, another one!) at this point that the docs are just terribly outdated.

Comment: Please write this up as a bug report, too, so it does not fall under the table and is forgotten.

Comment: PostgreSQL has no autocommit on the server side. The "autocommit in session" mentioned above is an ECPG-specific feature that is implemented client-side by not implicitly starting any transaction.

Comment: My testing shows that your guess is actually wrong; DBD::Pg implements `AutoCommit=0` simply by issuing a `BEGIN`, then a `COMMIT` when it is turned back on.

Comment: Anyway, I filed a [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=82356) with CPAN.